# How to check if all values in column are False after mask

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, series

I have the following code which is filtering out certain values:

```
df_1['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_1['date'])
df_2['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_2['date'])
res = df_1.merge(df_2, on='order_id', suffixes=['_orig', ''])
m = res['date'].gt(res['date_orig']) | (res['date_orig'].isnull() & res['date'].notnull())
```

it results in:

```
0    False
1    False
2    False
3    False
4    False
5    False
6    False
7    False
8    False
9    False
```

How would one check to see if one of the results is True?

Here is what I attempted:

```
if m is False:
    print('false')
else:
    print('true')
```

The result always runs false when this is attempted even if I have the following result:

```
0    False
1    False
2    False
3    False
4    True
5    False
6    False
7    False
8    False
9    False
```

If any of these values are true I want this to return true.

Any insight is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do:

```
any(m)
```

If m is a boolean list and any one of the element is True, `any(m)` will return `True`

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Series.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.any.html):

```
if m.any():
    print('at least one true')
else:
    print('all false')
```